# IPC with gRPC in UWP Application

Tags: c#, uwp, grpc, ipc

I want to communicate UWP Application to .NET 6 Application. As per my study I can do it via gRPC as IPC mechanism. I followed [this sample App](https://github.com/XamlBrewer/UWP-gRPC-Sample). This App run in debug Mode but in release Build i faced exception. Here is my code snippet where exception Occurred.

```
private async void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            // Just to get rid of the async warning.
            await Task.Delay(0);

            WriteLog("Transporter Room Panel Startup.");
            WriteLog("- Openening a channel.");
            _channel = new Channel("localhost:50051", ChannelCredentials.Insecure);

            // Optional: deadline.
            // Uncomment the delay in Server Program.cs to test this.
            // await _channel.ConnectAsync(deadline: DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds(2));

            WriteLog("- Channel open.");

            _client = new TransporterClient(_channel);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string exc = ex.ToString();
            
            WriteLog("Exception: " + exc);
        }
    }
```

I got exception during execution of this line of code
`_channel = new Channel("localhost:50051", ChannelCredentials.Insecure);` in Release build but it works fine in debug mode.

Call stack of exception is:

```
    System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: path1
   at System.IO.Path.Combine(String, String) + 0x50
   at Grpc.Core.Internal.NativeExtension.LoadNativeMethodsUsingExplicitLoad() + 0x69
   at Grpc.Core.Internal.NativeExtension.LoadNativeMethods() + 0xd3
   at Grpc.Core.Internal.NativeExtension..ctor() + 0x12
   at Grpc.Core.Internal.NativeExtension.Get() + 0x6a
   at Grpc.Core.GrpcEnvironment.GrpcNativeInit() + 0x68
   at Grpc.Core.GrpcEnvironment..ctor() + 0x97
   at Grpc.Core.GrpcEnvironment.AddRef() + 0x7d
   at Grpc.Core.Channel..ctor(String, ChannelCredentials, IEnumerable`1) + 0x102
   at XamlBrewer.Uwp.Grpc.Client.MainPage.<MainPage_Loaded>d__4.MoveNext() + 0xef
```

What is the fix for above exception?

I want to communicate from UWP to .NET 6 App without using App Service.

1. Above approach is right/wrong?
2. Is there any other way to do that?